# Java: How to use AbsolutePath as a Link

Tags: java, uri, absolute-path

I´m writing some Java and one of my task is to convert the Input/Output in to html. Well everything is going good, I can read some files and get the path of those files. Now I´m trying to convert the path in to a normal link so:

```
"<a href=" + file.getAbsolutePath() + " target=_parent>"
```

Works pretty good, but:

- One, the explorer show an error that it can´t read the file, example:
  a jpg or a word file..
- Two, if the path have a blank like: "my picture.jpg"
  recognize everything after the blank as a normal text...

can someone give me a Tipp, How to fix that, or I just using the wrong method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `toURI()` method that turns the file path into a URI:

```
file.getAbsoluteFile().toURI().toString()
```

Comment: error: cannot find symbol but it was enough just with file.toURI() now everything works great!!  Thanks!